# Spring-WS SecurityInterceptor operation level

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-security, spring-ws

I have a Spring-WS service using `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` that has several interceptors:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">        
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref local="loggingInterceptor"/>
            <ref local="validatingInterceptor"/>
            <ref local="securityInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

My `securityIntercetor` is a `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` interceptor.

Everything works fine, except that the `securityIntercetor` is at the `@Endpoint` level, I want it to be at the `@PayloadRoot` (operation).

The way I authenticate users is using `UsernameToken`, then I go against LDAP and get the roles and depending on the role I want to allow/prohibit the user to execute an operation.

I assume there isn't a out of the box solution for this.

So my question is: how in the `securityIntercetor` can I get what operation is being called so I can check depending on my settings to allow or not the execution of a specific operation.

Or maybe you have other ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way of doing this.

What I did is I created another interceptor (and placing him first in the list of interceptor being called), that would save the current operation and then when Spring hits my security interceptor I will get the method from a request scoped bean that was created by my first interceptor.